# JDBC SQL - How do I break down a range of values, e.g. SAVE001-SAVE100?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have a database that stores promo codes. It looks something like this...

1   SAVE001-SAVE100

2   YES200-YES300

Now, how do I extract the values SAVE001-SAVE100 from the database and then break them down so that it looks like SAVE001, SAVE002, SAVE003, SAVE004...?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
String[] promos = rs.getString().split("-");
```

That considering if you have a `ResultSet` object `rs`, and your value returned as String from your `DB`.

And Use in order to print the value.

```
Arrays.toString(promos);
```

Comment: I get '[Ljava.lang.String;@46d485' printed instead of SAVE001, SAVE002, SAVE003...

Comment: Sorry, I still keep getting '[Ljava.lang.String;@' being printed to my terminal.

Comment: Oh, this because the regular array didn't override  the toString method. use `Arrays.toString(array That you want to peint);` to print the values.

Comment: what do you mean by Arrays.toString(array That you want to peint);?  Is it something like Arrays.toString(promos[])?

Comment: I meant the array that you want to print its values, and yes like: `Arrays.toString(promos);` with out `[]`.

Comment: Yeah, I want to print promos. I tried the Arrays.toString(promos); but it printed '[Ljava.lang.String;@46d485 instead. How do I fix this? I want to print the values in promos

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] promos = rs.getString("Column name").split("-");
```

Then you can do sorting  like this (I think):

```
Arrays.sort(promos);
```

Then if you print it you must use `for-loop` or use the method `Arrays.toString(promos)` or `Arrays.deepToString(arr)`.

You better to post the database table of promos to see how the data arranged and maybe you will get better answer.

Hope you I helped...

Comment: I tried your code, and I get '[Ljava.lang.String;@2f594d' printed instead of SAVE001, SAVE002, SAVE003...

Comment: I think you are always printing System.out.println(promos); that is why it is showing to string represetation of a string array. use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(promos)); it will print the string returned by the toString method.